# Scanf function stops after newline and reads just a small part of input ( should ignore newline and tabs )

Tags: c, string, char, int, scanf

The whole question in a short version:

I want to load this input

```
4
     CAAC

      28    EAAEB5
  F489AD95
```

but all I can get from it is :

```
4
```

**I am trying to make from that input these params : `4` `CAAC` `28` `EAAEB5` `F489AD95`**

--------------- Detailed Explanation with my code ---------------------------

I am new in C language and I am trying to make an input, to go be as a string and work with it after ... I have a problem to handle `"Whitespaces"` such as [ `"\n"` , `"\t"` and `" "` ] Here is an input I gave to my Compiler :

```
4
     CAAC

      28    EAAEB5
  F489AD95
```

there are bunch of spaces, tabs etc. The thing I want to do, is to read it and replace \n and \t ( in clode bellow i am trying to ignore it, because of right after scanf() finds \n it skips the rest of it.

This is one of the codes I tried for now:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int number;
    char chr[200];

    // %d -> I know that there should be number at the beginning, so until character / space appears, I want to read the number.
    // scanf("%d", &number);

    // ignores \n and \t and then puts it in chr
    scanf(" %[^\t\n]s", &chr);

    // last should be \n so this is just acheck if there is ( its gonna be in if later )
    scanf("%c");

    printf("\n %s", chr);
    printf("\n Heythere");

    return 0;
}
```

This is an output I have got:

```
4                                                                                                                                                                                           
 Heythere
```

I have been thinking about putting it in a loop, but the problem is, that last character is "\n" and it can appear multiple times in a given string.

I am currently trying to find the best option for scanf() to read those lines and ignore new lines

/////////

In other words :

I am trying to make from that input these params : `4` `CAAC` `28` `EAAEB5` `F489AD95`

Any idea how to fix it, to be able to buffer it completely ? ( also the best answer that will help me, will be the one, that will replace those "\n" and "\t" with one single " " ( space ) Thank you for your answers in advance ( also sorry if its really simple and answer like million times ... I am stuck here for a week )

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\t\n]s", &chr);` is a type error. Also, that `s` in the format string will never match. It's also a buffer overflow waiting to happen. `scanf("%c");` has undefined behavior (missing argument for `%c`).

Comment: okay, so after I fix scanf("%c"); , how should I fix scanf(" %[^\t\n]s", &chr); ?

Comment: I don't know, I'd have to look at the `scanf` manual and I hate `scanf`, so I normally don't bother.

Comment: I am gonna read carefully scanf documentation then, but still, what woul you recommend to use instead of it ? :)

Comment: Is this an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Are you actually trying to read the five data items `4`, `CAAC`, `28`, `EAAEB5` and `F489AD95` without any separating whitespace?

Comment: Depends on what you're actually trying to do, which is not clear to me.

Comment: as I can see I have fall into X-Y problem ... and well yes, I am trying to read tose 5 data items ...

Comment: Format spec `%s` automatically filters whitespace. `scanf("%s", chr)` will read each one, so do that five times, perhaps into different variables.

Comment: I am gonna edit my question, to make it more readable and to be easily understandable

Comment: @WeatherVane scanf("%s", chr) it does not filter "\n"

Comment: It does not filter *trailing* newline. It filters *leading* whitespace. Any trailing whitespace becomes leading whitespace for the next item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, all you need is a loop to read five strings:

```
char data[5][100];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (scanf("%99s", data[i]) != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected input failure (i = %d)\n", i);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Now the elements of the array will contain the 5 strings ('words') you supplied.

By design, the [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) functions largely ignore white space except to the extent it separates strings or numbers.  All but three of the conversion specifiers skip over leading white space — the exceptions are `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets), and `%n`.

The `%99s` conversion specification skips leading white space (blanks, tabs, newlines), consumes up to 99 characters that aren't white space, and stops at the first white space (or when the string is full), leaving the white space in the input stream to be processed by the next input if the string wasn't full.

Obviously, you have to work a bit harder if you don't know that there are five strings to read — but the basic idea is the same.

If you want to conserve or change newlines, tabs, blanks, then `scanf()` is not the correct tool for the job.  It doesn't care about white space and you do — that's not going to lead to happiness.  Then you use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read the lines of input, and you can process the blanks, tabs and newlines as you see fit.

Comment: The thing is that it can be changed , it depends on input , also the number of input is written as a 1st part of it , problem is, that it can be connected to one if the strings ( here is an example: 7BB CAB BB AA 2B 5B 7C

Comment: That should be made clearer in the question.  You read the number (`if (scanf("%d", &num_strings) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "Expected number but didn't get one\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` and then arrange appropriate memory allocation.  If you only need to process each word in turn and don't need them all in memory at once in an array, then you can use a simple `char data[100];` variable to read each string and then process it in the loop.  If you need them all in memory at the same time, you need to allocate the memory.  Maybe `char data[num_strings][100];` or maybe using `malloc()`.

Comment: But so far thank you for your answer :) Right now I think that all I need to do is to somehow separate number from characters and then define the first array value ;)

Comment: thank you :) Gonna play with it and see if it works, gonna let you know if it solved the problem

Comment: The choice of 100 in my code is arbitrary — it's large enough that it'll read most words, but small enough not to be a big problem.  Note that the VLA (variable length array) allocation (`char data[num_strings][100];`) could lead to stack overflow if `num_strings` is big enough.  If the number is (say) 10,000 or more — using a megabyte or so of memory — then you should probably use dynamic memory allocation.  If it is unlikely to be that big, then the VLA is probably OK.  Note that VLA support is mandatory in C99, optional in C11, but formally non-existent in C90.

Comment: thank you :) at the end it has worked for me :) ( gonna post another question in a lil so if you want to, you can give it a try eighter :) )

Answer (score 3):

**You have several options:**

- Use official discussion thread in IS
- Ask any of the consultants during their time
- Alternatively, ask them for another time, if you can't come
- Write an email to any of the consultants

[My feelings about this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY51j.jpg)

Comment: Heh as I can see ai do not have other option, I was already planning to write it in discussion forum :)

Comment: Oh I have solve this on using decimals and hex only, I though its an answer on a newer topic